# USA Consumer Law - Can issuer of gift card expire card without expiry date on card?

Tags: united-states, consumer-protection

I bought a highend graphics card from BestBuy. Nvidia offered a game on the card.
The invoice **didn't** have an expiry date at all or a website to refer to regarding terms and conditions.

I tried the code and it didn't work. I contacted customer support and they told me the promo expired and they cannot help me.

What does the law of the USA say regarding informing me as a customer with the expiry date?

Do they have the right to make my coupon expire without any prior notice?

Again, there is no reference to the sentence of "terms and conditions apply or visit a website for more information" in the invoice.

Comment: I've found that these expiration dates are often printed on the box itself. You have the same problem with the Vudu video service and buying the Disc + Digital copies, you have to look on the back of the case for the "offer expiration date".

Comment: It is bundled as serial on invoice not on a card inside the box.

Answer (score 1):

There are kinds of gift cards which people buy, and there are laws governing them. At the federal level, there is the [CARD Act of 2009](https://www.ftc.gov/sites/default/files/documents/statutes/credit-card-accountability-responsibility-and-disclosure-act-2009-credit-card-act/credit-card-pub-l-111-24_0.pdf) which in §1693l–1(c) says

> it  shall  be  unlawful  for  any  person  to  sell  or  issue  a
>   gift  certificate,  store  gift  card,  or  general-use  prepaid  card
>   that   is subject to an expiration date.

but it does allow an exception if

> the  expiration  date  is  not  earlier  than  5  years   after  the 
>   date  on  which  the  gift  certificate  was  issued,   or  the  date 
>   on  which  card  funds  were  last  loaded  to  a   store gift card or
>   general-use prepaid card; and the  terms  of  expiration  are  clearly
>   and  conspicuously stated.

However, a "card" or piece of paper which entitles you to install free software would probably not satisfy the legal requirements of being a "gift card" in this sense. As I understand the situation, you purchased a piece of computer hardware, and as a promotional bonus they allowed you to install a game. The terms of the law are defined in subsection (a). A "General-use prepaid card" is among other things "issued in a requested amount", and not "for a specific thing". A "gift certificate" is  likewise "issued in a specified amount", as is a "Store gift card". The definition excludes "loyalty, award, or promotional gift card", which is what you seem to have been offered. If you had purchased a certificate of some kind that entitles you to get this software (not gotten a certificate in connection with buying something else), then it cannot expire in less that 5 years, and the expiration date has to be conspicuous. But that law does not apply to "bonuses" that you get when you buy another thing.